# mousemove event JS

Tags: javascript, settimeout, mouse-event

Помогите пожалуйста, не лезет в голову как реализовать. Когда пользователь не двигает  мышкой несколько секунд на div`е, нужно чтобы вызывалось событие при спокойствии мыши. Проще говоря, мне нужен антоним на mousemove.

Comment: На событии мыши запоминаете время последнего события. И вешаете таймер, который раз в несколько секунд проверяет это самое время, если прошло уже достаточно времени с последнего события, значит произошло то чего ожидали. Если прошло мало времени, то планируем следующее выполнение таймера через N секунд минус кол-во времени с последнего события (так что бы таймер сработал вовремя). Или как вариант на событии мыши просто сбрасываете предыдущий таймер и запускаете новый

Comment: Спасибо за совет, помогли в некоторой степени)

Answer (score 7):

```js
var meBlock = document.getElementById('me-block'),
  t;

meBlock.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  meBlock.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
   meBlock.style.color = "#fff";
  meBlock.innerHTML = 'МЫША БЕГАЕТ';
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    meBlock.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    meBlock.innerHTML = 'МЫША СТАЛ';
  }, 1000);
});

meBlock.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  meBlock.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  meBlock.style.color = "#000";
  meBlock.innerHTML = 'МЫША НЕТЬ';
  clearTimeout(t);
})
```

```css
#me-block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="me-block"></div>
```

Comment: Пасиб, уже решил, примерно так же)